# Angular2 - Show link as active for two routes

Tags: angular

I want a route to be active for either: "www.example.com" or "www.example.com/route-name".

I know I can simply re-direct from / to /route-name however I just cant help but feel this is bad practice and it would be the code directing the logic...

To show a route is active I have the following for route-name:

```
<a [routerLink]="['route-name']"><span>Route Name</span></a>
```

If this where PHP I would do something like:

```
($route == '/' OR $route == 'route-name') ? 'active' : ''
```

How do you do this sort of condition with NG2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this using `[class]` property binding,

```
<a [routerLink]="['route-name']" [ngClass]="{'active': activeLink}"></a>
```

In your menu component ngOnChanges,check for the router's path and then assign true to activeLink as

```
if(this.router...){
this.activeLink=true;
}
```